# Is it possible to turn on spaceless mode only in certain situations in twig?

Tags: twig, template-engine

I want to do something like this:

```
{% if compress %}{% spaceless %}{% endif %}
...
{% if compress %}{% endspaceless %}{% endif %}
```

I'm trying to pass `['compress' => true]` to the template from PHP to turn on `spaceless` mode. But it causes an error; template tags need to be nested properly.

Is there any technique that would let me turn spaceless on/off from PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to restructure your template to do something like this instead.

```
{% import _self as example %}
{% macro stuff(obj) %}
  output stuff with {{ obj.name }}, etc...
{% endmacro %}

{% if compress %}
  {% spaceless %}
    {{ example.stuff(bla) }}
  {% endspaceless %}
{% else %}
    {{ example.stuff(bla) }}
{% endif %}
```

Using [macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) avoids you have to duplicate the content. The import statement at the top is important, so don't forget it.

Answer (score -2):

page.twig:

```
{% block page %}
page content
{% endblock %}
```

index.twig:

```
{% extends 'page.twig' %}
{% block page %}
    {% if compress %}
        {% spaceless %}
           {{ parent() }}
        {% endspaceless %} 
    {% else %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```